# Inequality of side of triangle

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, triangles

If a,b,c are sides of triangle and x,y,z are positive real number, is possible to prove inequality below?

$$2a^2x+2b^2y+2c^2z\geq (b^2+c^2)x+(a^2+c^2)y+(a^2+b^2)z$$

Comment: Hint: [Rearrangement Inequality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality)

Comment: Can you explain for me your solution

Comment: I try to prove without suppose that x>=y>=z and a>=b>=c is possible?

Answer (score 1):

This is not correct. For example, let a=1, b=c=2, X=1, y and z are very small. Then left hand side is close to 2, and right to 8